# How to remove space between border and list with HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, border, space

I want to remove space between the left side of the border and the unordered list.

On the right side, there is barely any space between the list and border; that's how I want it to be on the left side too.

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid red;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Kilimanjaro</li>
  <li>Table Mountain</li>
  <li>Matterhorn</li>
  <li>Denali</li>
  <li>Cerro Torre</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Show us your HTML and make an executable code snippet.

Comment: <ul>
<li>Kilimanjaro</li>
<li>Table Mountain</li>
<li>Matterhorn</li>
<li>Denali</li>
<li>Cerro Torre</li>
</ul>

Comment: Try this in css.

ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:0;
}​

Comment: Ived tried padding-left and it still wont remove that white space :///

Comment: Did you use this too  list-style:none ?

Comment: yeah I tried list-style:none but I didnt really change anything :/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the padding for `li` too.

```
li{
  padding:0.125em;
}
```

Comment: hmm still cant get it to work, can u show me what exactly you mean?

Comment: that made it bigger :/

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the **-webkit-padding-start** property. By default is set to 40px in Chrome:

[image: --webkit-padding-start]

You can remove it and then add the padding you want:

```
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid red;
  padding: 1px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
     -moz-padding-start: 0px;
          padding-start: 0px;
}
```

Check the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmkekgar/)

Comment: ahhh I see, thanks, but also if I wanted to edit the <li> tags and make them larger, then it doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

```
ul{
  font-size:0;
} 
li{
  font-size: 16px; /*Don`t forget to set font size for li.*/  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just set the padding in ul element as 0. It should look like:

```
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid red;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```
<ul>
  <li>Kilimanjaro</li>
  <li>Table Mountain</li>
  <li>Matterhorn</li>
  <li>Denali</li>
  <li>Cerro Torre</li>
</ul>
```